# Script to save lots of shapefiles into different CRS in QGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis

I have a lot of shapefiles that I need to save in a different CRS... is it possible to automate this process with a script in QGIS?

Comment: Are the shapefiles already loaded into QGIS or do they reside in the same directory?

Comment: I was thinking about exporting the shapefiles already loaded but for me it's the same...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For shapefiles already loaded into QGIS, you can use the following code in the **Python Console**:

```
import processing

# Set path to where you want the shapefiles saved
shapes_result = "path/to/results//" 
# Set crs
crs = 'EPSG:4326'  

shapefiles = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values() 
for shapes in shapefiles:
        processing.runalg("qgis:reprojectlayer", shapes, crs, shapes_result + shapes.name())
```

---

I used *QGIS 2.12.3-Lyon* with *Processing* plugin version 2.12.2.

---

**Edit**:

The following code which you can run as a **script** reprojects the loaded layers in QGIS and saves them in their original folder. Note that they are prefixed with "New_" as you won't be able to overwrite the shapefiles (since they're already in use):

```
##Reproject shapefiles=name

import os, processing
from qgis.core import QgsMapLayerRegistry

# Set crs
crs = 'EPSG:4326'  

shapefiles = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values() 
for shapes in shapefiles:
    myfilepath = shapes.dataProvider().dataSourceUri()
    (myDirectory,nameFile) = os.path.split(myfilepath)
    processing.runalg("qgis:reprojectlayer", shapes, crs, myDirectory + "/" + "New_" + shapes.name())
```

Comment: I tested the code... it works properly if I run it into the Python Console, but it generates an error (name 'QgsMapLayerRegistry' is not defined) if I execute it as a script... I was also thinking if it is possible to export the shapefiles to the path of their "original" (suppose I have loaded shapefiles from different folders)

Comment: @BryanCiceri - Yes, the code was meant for the **Python Console**. I've edited my post to include a code which you can run as a script, it also saves the layers in their original locations with a slightly new file name =)

Comment: Excuse me @Joseph, but sometimes I obtain the "[Errno 9] Bad file descriptor"... and the script stops... do you know how can I fix it or handle it in order to make the script continue?

Comment: @BryanCiceri - Hmm make sure you have permission to write to the directory of the shapefiles you loaded. Also make sure there are only shapefiles loaded and not rasters. I can't seem to replicate your issue here.

Comment: I dunno why but if I run the script again after the error it doesn't stop no more and ends correctly...

Comment: @BryanCiceri - Strange but atleast it's working I guess ;)