# Can you change the default CRS in Photo2Shape?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-plugins, photo2shape

I'm running Photo2Shape to create a shapefile that I then process through Points2One in order to create a line to make a buffer layer.  When I run Photo2Shape it outputs a shapefile in wgs84 which makes every layer after that the same CRS.  My project default set to EPSG:102003.

Is there a way to set the default to another system so I can use meters to create a buffer layer later on?  Neither Points2One nor Photo2Shape have the option.  I know you can use 'save as' to save the shapefile in another coordinate system but this isn't efficient when I need to do this several hundred times.

Comment: Your camera is capturing GPS co-ordinates, so it will be in WGS84 already, you will have to re-project at some stage.

Answer (score 1):

You can **edit the source code** for the plugin and change the CRS so that all outputs have the same CRS you defined.

The file you need to edit is the *photoimporter.py* file and can be found in your `.qgis2` directory. For example, for me it is located in:

```
C:/Users/Me/.qgis2/python/plugins/photo2shape/photoimporter.py
```

Look for the `def _newShapefile(self)` function and you will see the line which contains setting the CRS for all outputs. Change the initial value of `4326` to `102003`:

[image: photoimporter.py]

Save the edit then either reload the plugin or restart QGIS.

Comment: I think you would also have to re-project the co-ordinates before writing them to the shapefile.

Comment: @Vesanto - I haven't really used this plugin so can't confirm if the coordinates need to be reprojected, however I assumed they would be when being written to a shapefile using the [QgsVectorFileWriter() class](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter.html)...?

Comment: I would assume it reads the raw GPS data from the image EXIF data and creates a point using that. If so it would be reading WGS84 co-ordinates. But can't confirm.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. It shows that it's in the projection I want but it doesn't match up with the rest of the project.

Comment: @Joseph Looking at the metadata after trying this it returns with the correct Layer Spatial Reference System but the wrong In layer spatial reference system units.  eg
reprojected in qgis - xMin,yMin 534761.91,-441796.46 : xMax,yMax 558234.14,-404156.30 
source code edit- xMin,yMin -90.1312,34.8598 : xMax,yMax -89.8591,35.193

Comment: @brink - That is unfortunate. I guess Vesanto is right in that you may need to reproject your loaded shapefiles but you can do this automatically as described in this post: [Script to save lots of shapefiles into different CRS in QGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180956/script-to-save-lots-of-shapefiles-into-different-crs-in-qgis)

Comment: @Joseph Can't win them all.  I started using the modeler which has a reprojection function you can add to the work flow so I am able to avoid having unnecessary layers.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @brink - Most welcome, glad you found a decent workaround =)